# @@RowCount return 1 even the previous select condition was False

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have this simple code

```
declare @a int, @b int 
select @a=sum(1), @b=1 from syscolumns where 1 = 2
select @@rowcount, @a, @b
```

The result is : `@@rowcount=1`, `@a=null`, `@b=1`

@a = null is fine to me, but how come @@rowcount and @b=1

SQLFiddle : https://rextester.com/PKCB94229

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because scalar aggregates (no `GROUP BY`) always return one row even on an empty input (assuming no `HAVING` clause eliminates it)

`select sum(1) from syscolumns where 1 = 2` returns a resultset with one row, so `@@ROWCOUNT` is correctly reported as `1`.

If you want to count the input rows from a query that assigns scalar aggregates to variables then assigning `COUNT(*)` to another variable would be simplest.